# jQuery's `.not` not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm accomplishing a collapsible menu in jQuery. After clicking on any header it's next sibling (the box) should be expanded and all other boxes should be collapsed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="finbox" id="finbox1">
    <div class="finheader" id="finheader1">
        <div class="finleft">1. Before you place your order &gt; sign in  </div> <div class="finright"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="finbody">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="finbox" id="finbox2">
    <div class="finheader" id="finheader2">
        <div class="finleft">2. Delivery Address </div> <div class="finright"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="finbody">

    </div>
</div>

...
...
...
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.finheader').click(function(e){
    $(this).next().slideDown();    // .finbody slide down
    $(this).next().addClass('selbdy');
    $(this).addClass('finsel');
    $('.finbody:not(.selbdy)').slideUp(); // All .finbody except  '.selbdy' slide down
    console.log('Slide Down');
});
```

Comment: wanna put this in a fiddle?

Comment: Even `$('.finbody').not('.selbdy').slideUp(); ` is not working.

Comment: both elements are going to have `.selbdy` after awhile since you never remove the class/reset the elements

Comment: Add `$('.selbdy').slideUp()` before you add class to the new element. http://jsfiddle.net/r1p5bf3f/

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$(this).next().addClass('selbdy');
$(this).addClass('finsel');
```

With:

```
$('.finbody').removeClass('selbdy');
$(this).next().addClass('selbdy');
$('.finheader').removeClass('finsel');
$(this).addClass('finsel');
```

The rest of you code looks good and should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('.finheader').click(function(e){
  $('.finbody').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideDown();
  console.log('Slide Down');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/28gug87k/

Comment: It seems to be working for me, without the need to add a temporary class

Answer (score 0):

You will find it easier to work from `$('.finheader').not(this)` .

You also need to remove any 'finsel'/'selbdy' classes previously added.

```
$('.finheader').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('finsel').next().slideDown().addClass('selbdy');
    $('.finheader').not(this).removeClass('finsel').next().slideUp().removeClass('selbdy');
});
```

Comment: Nice. A good way to reduce LOC. But this type of chaining could slow things down a bit though.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't worry too much about performance here. Even if this code was 10 times slower than the fastest possible, it would still be plenty fast enough. By all means try, but I don't think you will squeeze too much extra performance out of it.

Comment: Also, chaining *per se* doesn't slow things down. It's better to chain than to start several consecutive lines with `$(this)`.